# Existing Directory Not Found by Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-handling

After a series of prompts to the user, my batch script assembles a directory path:

```
set RELEASE_PATH=!RELEASE_DRIVE!:\!CUSTOMER!\files\!RELEASE_LABEL!
```

The problem I am facing is when attempting to detect whether the folder at the end of this path already exists.  You'd think this is fairly straightforward, but the path evaluation always fails, even though the path exists.  However, when I run the same `if` statement from the command line, it works. -_-

```
if not exist !RELEASE_PATH! (
  echo DEBUG: Path %CD%\%RELEASE_LABEL% exists
  mkdir %RELEASE_LABEL%
) else (
  echo DEBUG: Path %CD%\%RELEASE_LABEL% does not exist
)
```

Running the batch file always echos the line for `DEBUG: Path %CD%\%RELEASE_LABEL% does not exist` even though it in fact does exist.  FYI, I have both `EnableExtentions` and `EnableDelayedExpansion` set.

A typical release path might be `R:\Widget_Co\files\Release_12.1`.  Any thoughts or ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check `echo DEBUG: Path %CD%\%RELEASE_LABEL% does not exist  [!RELEASE_PATH!]`. Use parentheses: `if not exist "!RELEASE_PATH!" (`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue had something to do with `EnableDelayedExpansion` being set.  I was able to put together this work-around using a for loop:

```
rem ## This clunky workaround with the for loop is required because a simple
rem ## `if not exist` command isn't working. It is believed that this has
rem ## something to do with EnableDelayedExpansion being set.  There is only one
rem ## element in the RELEASE_PATH variable being evaluated in this loop.

for /F %%i in ("!RELEASE_PATH!") do (
  if not exist %%i (
    mkdir %%i
  )
)
```